# Were there any incarnations of Varuna and Agni deva?

Tags: mahabharata

I know Vishnu had Dashavatara, Surya, Yama, Ashvins, Vayu, Brahma and Shiva also incarnated on earth.

Were there any incarnations of Varuna and Agni?

Comment: Agni is supposed to have taken 3 births. Although technically all three are him like some of Vishnu's incarnations are simultaneously completely him.

Comment: can you please vote up for the question